# How can I force a rebuild after saving a design element in XPages?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

This is just one of those things I've put up with ages, but I'd be interested to see if anyone has got a solution to the problem.

At some point during the day (there doesn't seem to be a pattern to it), when I rebuild my application after saving it, the changes will not be evident when testing in the browser. The only way to get them to show up is to issue a "tell http restart" on the server console or to restart the Designer client (which seems to issue a heavier rebuild command somewhere along the line).

Cleaning the project doesn't work either.

It's really just an annoyance, but one I'd love to be able to get rid of.

Comment: This may happen if someone else opens and builds your project on another computer. Practically, using "Refresh" on your project would help, because it is what happens when you restart your designer.

Comment: In the vast majority of cases I am the only developer touching the database (it's running on a local server) so not applicable for me. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

When it happens to me I remove all compiled stuff from Local->xsp and WebContent->WEB-INF->classes using Navigator view.

Then I run Project->Clean. This helps often.

[image: Navigator]

Restaring designer from time to time is also inevitable :)

Comment: Thanks, I have done similar, it just seems like this is a painful thing to do as well!